# Corfu not displaying child frame

Tags: frames, corfu

I have installed Corfu to use for completions but it's not doing or displaying anything. I have verified that it's enabled but at no point does a child frame appear. I've read the documentation but it doesn't mention anything about requiring me to install something additional or adding more configuration so my question is if I'm missing something here.

My Emacs version:

```
GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 1, aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0, NS appkit-2113.00 Version 12.0.1 (Build 21A559)) of 2023-02-22
```

My entire .emacs is as follows:

```
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(electric-pair-mode)
(ido-mode)
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(set-frame-font "Jetbrains Mono 14" nil t)

(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/Users/ruvensalamon/.local/bin")))

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)`
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(eval-when-compile
  (require 'package)
  (require 'use-package))

(use-package rust-mode
  :ensure t)

(use-package eglot
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'rust-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure))

(use-package corfu
  :ensure t
  :init
  (global-corfu-mode))

(use-package tree-sitter
  :ensure t)
```

Comment: Are you using Emacs on the terminal? If yes, then you need to install `corfu-terminal`.

Comment: @SwarnenduBiswas I saw that but no, I'm using the GUI. Installed emacs through `brew install --cask emacs`.